# SQL: how to filter by columns that are in different tables?

Tags: sql

Let's assume we have some table A which we want to query and that is related to another table, B, through a one to many relationship, so, A can have several B objects, and each B object can have only one A object. The problem is that when querying A, I need to filter by a column on table B. What is the best approach to do that?

If I use JOIN, then I end up with repeated A rows in the result. It is logical as an A object can have many B objects. In MySQL I can avoid duplicates by using GROUP BY but that is not possible on other database systems, they force you to use aggregated functions.

If I use subqueries, then I don't think that the performance is good because the most nested subquery could return a very high number of rows:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE ID IN (SELECT A_ID FROM B WHERE B.some_column = 'my-filter');
```

That subquery looks bad, if B had a huge number of rows it could be painful in terms of time/performance.

*A_ID is a foreign key on this example which points to the ID field in the table A.

So, what's the good way for doing this?

Comment: Depends on the dbms used. Some products optimize sub-queries better than others.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by repeat. If you want to return all students in a class with a last name starting with 'S', you don't want the class name to repeat?

Comment: `GROUP BY` is not intended for duplicate elimination, use SELECT DISTINCT instead. Newer MySQL versions don't allow invalid group by's (unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: Referring to the class and students example, what I would want is to get all classes which have at least 1 student with a last name starting with 'S'. If a class has 2 students meeting that filter, then it appears 2 times. That's what I mean with the repeated rows. I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

Use a join and a distinct

```
selct distinct A.*
from A
inner join B
    on B.ID = A.ID
where B.ColumnB = 'Filter'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with `GROUP BY` on other database systems! They are just forcing you to write the entire columns in the `GROUP BY` clause **or** with aggregate functions **as it should be** as opposed to MySQL that allows this stupid thing  . So:

```
SELECT a.Col1,a.Col2,a.Col3...
FROM A
JOIN B
 ON(a.id = b.id)
WHERE B.some_column = 'my-filter'
GROUP BY a.Col1,a.Col2,a.Col3...
```

Comment: This makes sense. The only problem I could have is that I am modifying a layer of a Java application which manages accesses to database and it would be difficult to guess all the column names of the table which I am querying at each moment. Although I think it could be possible by reflection, as column names are methods on entity classes that are converted into tables by the ORM tool.